# Is my object being copied when sent to multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

TL;DR: If I pass a data object to a `multiprocessing.Process` worker, will the data object be automatically copied?

Context: I'm doing a data science project where it's imperative that I don't predict on the same data I train on. For readability reasons I have created a cross-validation object that stores all the data and lets you select the active fold in the data object. In addition I want to use the multiprocessing library to train several models concurrently. In my head I can envision the following problematic scenario:

1. In the data object, fold 0 is selected by process 0
2. Process 0 fetches the training data from data object, which currently is the data in folds 1-4.
3. In the data object, fold 1 is selected by process 1.
4. Process 0 predicts the model on the active fold, which now has **been changed to Fold 1.** This means that Process 0 has trained and predicted on the same data.

To make absolutely sure this doesn't happen I make an explicit deepcopy of the data object before it is sent to the Process. This is done in the following code:

```
for i_cpu in range(N_CPU):
    data_obj_copy = copy.deepcopy(data_obj)
    workers.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=gridsearch, args=
        (
                data_obj_copy,
                model_generator,
                idc_per_cpu[i_cpu],
                results,
                X_reals_ground_truth
        )
    )
)
```

But this in turn eats a ton of memory. This leads me to my question: **Is making an explicit copy of my data object necessary?** From what I've understood the `multiprocessing` library does something called pickling, which might mean that the data object is copied regardless. If this is true then I me making a copy is unnecessary.

Also If you have suggestions on how you would do this more efficiently that is also appreciated.

Comment: It depends mostly on the OS. On Windows for example it will always be copied.

Comment: I'm running Linux. Does this mean that my fear of the scenario above happening is reasonable?

Comment: as I know it pickles data and send using file - processes don't have shared memory.